# How do I make the rounded corners of the overflow menu without the ripple effect coming off?

Tags: android, kotlin, menu

I am trying to create an overflow menu with rounded edges, but when I modify the borders, the effect when selecting an item is drawn outside the menu.

I have this menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/empts"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dots"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item_ajustes"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
                android:title="Settings" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item_calificar"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_rate"
                android:title="Rate" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

I add this menu to the app with the next code:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    val inflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.overflow, menu)
    return true
}
```

I customize the menu with the next

```
<style name="Theme.HITT" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenuStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="OverflowMenuStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">-160dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/rounded_menu</item>
</style>
```

This is the rounded_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="16dp" />

</shape>
```

But when i click a item, te ripple effect appears out of the menu, how can I make the ripple effect draw only inside the menu?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We9RR.png)

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/35580220/12709358